Why is the Firebase Realtime Database page not showing anything when writing data to it? [Resolved]
I'm trying to make a simple app with Android Studio (Iguana) and using Firebase Realtime Database. I'm new to Android Studio and Firebase, so I've been following this youtube tutorial: here. I'm currently trying to test writing data to the database, but when clicking on the test button (see code below), nothing pops up in the data page.
Realtime Database rules:
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true"
  }
}

My kotlin code (This is a fragment named Quiz, not the main activity file. The app has a bottom navigation system), where I use a test button to try to write data to the database :
package com.example.apptitle

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import com.example.appTitle.databinding.FragmentQuizBinding
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.google.firebase.database.database

private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

class Quiz : Fragment() {
    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentQuizBinding

    private lateinit var firebaseRef: DatabaseReference
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }
        binding = FragmentQuizBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        firebaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("test")

        binding.testButton.setOnClickListener {
            firebaseRef.setValue("Hello, World!")
                .addOnCompleteListener{
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Data stored successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_quiz, container, false)
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            Quiz().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
    }
}

In the data tab of the Realtime Database page of the Firebase Console, when I click my test button, a message like test:"Hello, World!" is supposed to appear, but nothing shows up.
I'm new to Android Studio in general, so there might be some other problems in the code that I'm not aware of. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I've tried redoing the steps in the tutorial, updating my database rules to "true", making sure my app is connected, and checking if I had the right dependencies and SDKs. Screenshot here:
The Firebase Database Tool
I've also tried putting my database URL directly into firebaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("the url").getReference("test"), but still nothing appeared.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Does this toast ever show up: Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Data stored successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()? If not, you've likely not configured the app to connect to the database correctly, specifically step 3 here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add-config-file.

Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @. Besides that, have you tried to see what happens if the operation of writing the data fails?

Thanks a lot Frank van Puffelen, it works now. Also, apparently I had to put the setOnClickListener{} in OnViewCreated and not OnCreate.
